# Starting March 11, 2024, Events.list working location events will start to be returned

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I received an email "Update your applications to include notification improvements for Google Calendar API v3"  It says:

> Events.list: Specify the event types you need for your application as a parameter. Without making this change, **working location** events will start to be returned.

Looking at the "Events: list" API

> eventTypes    string  Event types to return. Optional. The default is ["default", "focusTime", "outOfOffice"].

The upcoming change is not clear to me, it does have "default" event type, so why not use it as **default** for the request?

Why "working location"?

Comment: This is a question you should be asking Google. They made the change, so they know why "working location" was chosen. It would appear that they've decided that "working location" is the "default" from March onward.

Comment: I would suggest asking this question here: [https://issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com) this way Google Product Engineers can answer your question and if this question is currently being asked by an exisiting member their answers towards that can help you as well.

Comment: I read it different. They are aligning the default filters between `Events.watch' and 'Events.list' and Wtahc already included the "workingLocation" and list did not.
I read this that they are aligning both to have the same. the Event Type `default` is a type, but the default values for the `eventTypes` paramater when not supplied is to use all types possible.
Events.wath mentions: The default is ["default", "focusTime", "outOfOffice", "workingLocation"].

Events.list currently mentions: The default is ["default", "focusTime", "outOfOffice"].

Comment: My guess is the same as @JohanBennink. But, I think it is unclear. Is there a way to test the March 11 behavior prior to March 11?